# Multiple maximum values

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I am on SQLite and have the following table and need to print the two names to which correspond the highest number of wins(25). By using the MAX() function, I only get the first of the two rows. How is it possible to print both rows that have the maximum value for wins?

[image]

Comment: Hum, in SQL Server you can do `TOP (1) WITH TIES` and get back two results. I think you will have to self-join onto the `MAX()` value

Answer (score 2):

If you query this way, it will return the highest two rows.

```
SELECT
    name,
    Wins
FROM
    table_name
ORDER BY Wins DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT name, Wins 
FROM (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Wins DESC) rnk
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE rnk = 1
```

This will return all the rows which will have the max number of `Wins` because all of them will be ranked as `1`.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont mind nested selects I think this should be getting all records have max wins

```
select name, wins from table where wins=(select max(wins) from table )
```

Answer (score 1):

All names with top 2 score

```
WITH maxw (wins) AS(
    SELECT DISTINCT wins 
    FROM tbl
    ORDER BY wins  DESC
    LIMIT 2
)
SELECT tbl.* 
FROM tbl 
JOIN maxw ON tbl.wins = maxw.wins;
```